# AppEngine: Why would anyone not want transactions?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions

The Google App Engine document says "**Transactions are an optional feature of the Datastore; you're not required to use transactions to perform Datastore operations.**". However, even a simplest of business transactions would require updating more than one entity kinds. A number of things can go wrong between updating those entity kinds, resulting in partial updates to the datastore. So, using transactions seem to be the simplest solution to maintain data integrity compared to a complex error handling mechanism that can reverse datastore updates when something goes wrong during updates to multiple entity kinds.

While I understand the need for entity groups and ancestor queries in transactions, they appear to be impractical restrictions. Added to that is the restrictions on cross-group transactions.

Am I totally missing the point? Are there guidelines on when I should use transactions; when transactions are absolutely necessary; when I should use error handling mechanisms to revert datastore changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datastore transactions are a trade-off.  When updating two entities in a transaction, you get the guarantee that the update will be transactional: it either succeeds completely (all changes applied) or fails completely (no changes applied).  In exchange, all changes to the entity group are serialized: if two users try to modify the same entity group concurrently, the first one to succeed wins, and the second one is cancelled and has to be retried.  The two users "contend" for the entity group, and must slow down their updates so only one change is applied at a time.

If you put all of your entities in the same entity group, your app would only be able to make a few changes per second.  This would not be scalable to many hundreds of concurrent users.  This is why the datastore lets you define the "locality" of your transactions in your data model.  Concurrent updates that do not need transactionality can be applied simultaneously on different datastore machines.

You can think of how to model your entity groups in different ways.  You can start from your observation that the ideal case for your business logic would be for all entities to be in the same group, then start breaking your data models apart into separate groups when concurrent updates are a benefit and transactionality is not needed.  Or you can start with every hypothetical entity in its own group, then start identifying cases where entities need to be updated together in a transaction and group them accordingly.  This latter strategy is usually more practical, since there's no other reason for two entities to be in the same group, and it's easier to not worry about contention issues when they're not explicitly introduced by grouping.

A good rule of thumb is for user-specific data-- data that only one user, or a fixed number of users, would update-- can live in its own group.  The tricky cases are when multiple arbitrary users might update the same group, and many apps have such cases.  Sometimes you have to live with contention to get correct data operations.  There are ways to improve user experiences in these cases, such as by trading the strong consistency of the primitive datastore transaction for the eventual consistency of performing that transaction at a "later" time (which could be mere seconds later), such as via a task queue.